# "invalid or unexpected token scanned" model error in WinBugs

Tags: winbugs, r2winbugs

by using

```
     model {
for(i in 1:N){
n[i] ~ dpois(mu[i])
mu[i] <-­ pow(t[i]/beta, alpha) 
 }
alpha ~ dunif(1,100) 
beta ~ dunif(1,100)
}
```

WinBugs give error"invalid or unexpected token scanned"
kindly consider the above model and give me the suitable solution to remove that error...